# Printing python code to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I have to print to PDF a discrete amount of python script. The code should be included as text, rather than image, as it must be checked by an anti-plagiarism mechanism (I do not have to take care of this, it is just requested that the pdf is not made from an image, that's all). It is also necessary to have syntax highlighting.

Do you have any suggestion regarding a specific tool for this?

Comment: I guess you have several unrelated problems here. Can you please eloborate your question a bit more? You can print any code by going into your code editor and press Print button.

Comment: There are probably many solutions, but Sphinx could do this: http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/code.html

Comment: Notepad++ can export rich text so your syntax highlighting stays intact. Look under Plugins>NppExport.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the anti-plagiarism part, I can't help you.  For printing a py script with syntax highlighting, a traditional tool is `enscript`:

```
enscript -E -q -Z -p - -f Courier10 readmaya.py | ps2pdf - out.pdf
```

Here, `enscript` does the syntax highlighting and produces postscript. You could use any of several possible tools for the second step of converting postscript to pdf.  I have shown here `ps2pdf` which is from the ghostscript package.

#### Installation

On a Debian- or Unbuntu-like system, `enscript` can be installed with:

```
apt-get install enscript
```

On a Debian- or Unbuntu-like system, `ps2pdf` is part of the `ghostscript` package which is likely already installed.  If it isn't. run:

```
apt-get install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using vim, then you can do this:

```
vim abc.py -c ":hardcopy > abc.ps" -c ":q"
```

You will get abc.ps with syntax highlight, then

```
ps2pdf abc.ps abc.pdf
```

Comment: any idea how to do this but for latex instead of postscript?

Comment: I used the `:TOhtml` variant...

Answer (score 0):

For anti-plagiarism check, you can use urllib2 to do a google search including a quoted text of what you want to check:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.co.in/search?q="python+curl"')
html = response.read()
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python) SO link for more details.

For pdf-printing part, what I normally do is create an html template of my text/document and then use the [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) python library to generate the pdf:

```
f=open('template.htm','r')
sourceHtml = unicode(f.read(), errors='ignore')
f.close()
sourceHtml = template.render(tvals)
sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__name__',sname)
sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__address__',saddress)
sourceHtml = sourceHtml.replace('__occupation__',soccupation)
packet = StringIO.StringIO() #write to memory
pisa.CreatePDF(sourceHtml,dest=packet)
```

Within the html template, you can use `<code>` or `<pre>` tags to format your scripts. Read my complete [article](http://www.prahladyeri.com/2013/11/how-to-generate-pdf-in-python-for-google-app-engine/) to understand more about this method of gerating pdfs in python.